# JSF - How to add h:graphicImage after f:selectItem element?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I am trying to add a h:graphicImage after the f:selecItem element, using this declaration:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection">

    <f:selectItem itemValue="some Value" itemLabel="some Label" itemDisabled="true">
         <h:graphicImage value="someImage.gif" title="someTitle" />
    </f:selectItem>

</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

and,

```
 <h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection">

    <f:selectItem itemValue="some Value" itemLabel="some Label" itemDisabled="true" />
    <h:graphicImage value="someImage.gif" title="someTitle" />        

</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

But, after rendering, the graphicImage element always show before the selectItem group.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, I've always used a dataTable over a list of beans.
The first column contained a selectBooleanCheckbox over a boolean property of the bean (p.e. selected), and I had more columns with the content that I need, so I could have got graphicImage or whatever else.

I only also needed an additional java logic to get the selected beans, and process the data.

Comment: Additional Java logic would not be necessary if you bind the checkboxes to the object behind the `var` attribute.